# Json to Html (No third party libraries)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm beginner with JSON and I'm very confused with this.

I have to convert any valid JSON string into valid HTML string to be able to visualize JSON on the web.

```
jsonToHtml(“[{‘x’: 1, ‘b’: 2}, {‘x’: 100, ‘b’: 200}]") => “x:1x:100"
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Input: [{‘x’: 1, ‘b’: 2}, {‘x’: 100, ‘b’: 200}]

Output: x:1x:100

The input is a generic and valid JSON. The output should be a valid HTML

Comment: "x:1x:100" isn't valid HTML, and where did the 'b' fields go? It's not clear what you want the output of this function to be.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got some issues with your single and double quote characters. It looks like maybe a copy and paste issue. The JSON you're showing is an acceptable syntax to create an array of objects, just remove the wrapping double quotes.

Use chrome's JavaScript console to paste in the following:

```
var myVar = [{'x': 1, 'b': 2}, {'x': 100, 'b': 200}]
// myVar now contains an array of the two objects.
// Test it out by attempting to access one of the objects properties.
myVar[0].b
```

## UPDATE

If the target browser supports ECMAScript 5, you can use the native JSON.parse function.

```
// Your JSON
var myJson = '[{"x": 1, "b": 2}, {"x": 100, "b": 200}]';
// Call our handy function that parses the JSON and set our variable with the parsed results.
var parsedObject = parseJson(myJson);
function parseJson(json) {
  return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

Comment: Yes, It was a copy an paste issue. How I can parse this [{'x': 1, 'b': 2}, {'x': 100, 'b': 200}] into an array? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/81nrt0n0/) :

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

var jsonString = "[{‘x’: 1, ‘b’: 2}, {‘x’: 100, ‘b’: 200}]";
var htmlString = htmlEscape(jsonString);
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery).